# Angular 2 select does not bind

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I played with this for quite awhile, selection list shows okey, but I cannot get it to display the selected value - it is empty. What am I doing wrong?

```html
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="ai_total_volume_select">Select Volume Range:</label>
    <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="items" id="ai_total_volume_select">
      <option [value]="item1">Select</option>
      <option [value]="item2">&lt; 0.5 cm3</option>
      <option [value]="item3">&gt; 0.5 cm3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <label>AAA</label>
  <div>{{selectedValue}}</div>
```

EDIT: I played a bit more and now know where the problem is coming from, but have no clue how to fix it. This select field is within:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
```

. And somehow it does not like it. Once I move it outside the form - it works! But I need it to be within the form. Other fields - checkboxes, inputs etc work perfectly fine in the same form...

Comment: Is this part of a reactive form or a template driven form?

Comment: I guess it is a mix.

Comment: That might be the problem -  I don't think you should try to combine these approaches.
From your original post it looks like you are using [template-driven](https://angular.io/guide/forms) forms where you define the form in the html template and the appropriate form directives.  Might be worth checking that documentation as I think you'll end up with issues if you try to combine the two - and it'll be pretty confusing!

Comment: Ah I see now @alexKhymenko has added comments, reflecting the same sentiments :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You messed up a little bit with value you are passing empty object. Add ' ' and it will work created [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8t7A66ZbWgE2RqdAmiSI?p=preview).

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="items" id="ai_total_volume_select">
  <option [value]="'item1'">Select</option>
  <option [value]="'item2'">&lt; 0.5 cm3</option>
  <option [value]="'item3'">&gt; 0.5 cm3</option>
</select>
```

or use value without []

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" novalidate>

 <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="items" id="ai_total_volume_select">
  <option value="item1">Select</option>
  <option value="item2">&lt; 0.5 cm3</option>
  <option value="item3">&gt; 0.5 cm3</option>
 </select>
</form>
```

for Reactive Forms use FormControlName

```
 <form [formGroup]="form">
   <select class="form-control" formControlName="selectedValue" name="items" id="ai_total_volume_select">
  <option value="item1">Select</option>
  <option value="item2">&lt; 0.5 cm3</option>
  <option value="item3">&gt; 0.5 cm3</option>
  </select>
<form>

{{form.controls.get('selectedValue').value}}
```

For better understanding template syntax read this [article](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax)

[ngForm](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm) and [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Comment: Thanks, Alex, I did change it to just value, but it still doesn't work if I keep it inside formGroup...

Comment: you try to use reactive forms with ngModel it doesnt' work :-)

Comment: You should pick one <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" novalidate>

Comment: or use formControl name instead of ngModel

Comment: I tried formControlName, it didn't work either. But why it works with other inputs then, like checkboxes etc?

Comment: @user1298416 updated the answer. Dont mix reactive forms with ngModel forms

Comment: Sorry, I'm very much a beginner in this. So, should I change 
<form [formGroup]="form" ... > to <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" novalidate> ? If I see [formGroup] it will mean reactive? And the one you've suggested is template-driven?

Comment: it depends what you want to use. If you want to use FormControlName use formGroup. If you want to use ngModel use ngForm.

Comment: @user1298416 added links

Comment: If I don't use ngModel, and use formControlName="abc". Can I bind to it like this - {{abc}}? I think it didn't quite work for me and I started using ngModel to bind the values...

Comment: I see your updated response. It answers my last question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Alex, I posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46481811/angular-2-select-does-not-bind-2nd-iteration 
Could you please take a look if you have time. Thanks!

Comment: @user1298416 Guess its answered :-)

Answer (score 2):

Unless the `item` values are defined in your component you don't need the `[value]` binding.

You can use standard html here:

```
<option value="item1">Select</option>
<option value="item2">&lt; 0.5 cm3</option>
<option value="item3">&gt; 0.5 cm3</option>
```

Comment: Thanks, Garth, seems like it is another problem though - I updated my question.