# Angular 2 select does not bind (2nd iteration)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, angular, typescript

I already asked similar question here [Angular 2 select does not bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46312284/angular-2-select-does-not-bind) and thought that it was solved. To follow suggestions I'm now trying to go with reactive forms everywhere and trying to use the suggested option for select:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
   <select class="form-control" formControlName="selectedValue" name="items" id="ai_total_volume_select">
  <option value="item1">Select</option>
  <option value="item2">&lt; 0.5 cm3</option>
  <option value="item3">&gt; 0.5 cm3</option>
  </select>
<form>

{{form.controls.selectedValue.value}}
```

The problem is it doesn't work... When it loads for the first time no selected value is displayed. I was only able to make it work using:

```
<select class="form-control" name="totalvolume" [(ngModel)]="totalvolume" [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone : true }">
     <option value="item1">Select</option>
     <option value="item2">&lt; 0.5 cm3</option>
     <option value="item3">&gt; 0.5 cm3</option>
</select>
```

But I want to do it properly and get rid of `ngModel`.

I also tried this:

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="progress" [value]="progress">
  <option value="NotStarted">Not Started</option>
  <option value="InProgress">In Progress</option>
  <option value="Finalized">Finalized</option>
</select>
<label>AAA{{form.controls.progress.value}}</label>
```

it displays the selected option I want (I set it up at the `ts file - progress = 'InProgress'`), but it somehow doesn't bind it properly as label `AAA` is empty after the form loads. If I switch select's value, it starts seeing it as there is `AAAFinalized` is displayed for example... I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
BTW `{{form.controls.get('selectedValue').value}}` gives an error

> "inline template:308:7 caused by:
>   self.parentView.context.form.controls.get is not a function"

Either "form.get('selectedValue').value" or "form.controls.selectedValue.value" work.

Comment: If you want to use reactive form (aka model-driven), you will need to work with typescript code (aka model). Don't try to do that all in HTML template.

Comment: could you please be more specific? i did set up initial value in the ts code: progress = 'InProgress'.

Comment: Post your `component.ts` where you set-up the formGroup

Comment: this.form = this.formBuilder.group({ ..., progress: [], ... })

Comment: Why did you leave it empty? Should have put the initial value in it. Something like `progress: [this.totalvolume]`

Comment: wow, okey i did:
 this.form = this.formBuilder.group({ ..., progress: [this.progress], ... }) and it seems to work. could you explain what happens there? Is "progress" in:
export class MyComponent implements OnInit { ... progress = 'InProgress'...} and "progress" in formBuilder.group different? Is it how you bind component and component's form together?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Model-driven form,  then first you should define the form controls inside the related component. in your case, put the below coding inside the component

```
form: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  createForm();
}

createForm(){
  this.form = this.fb.group({
      'selectedValue': ['', Validators.required],
  });
}
```

If you want to get the value of the select box, you can go ahead and run the below comand

```
var selectedValur = this.form.controls['selectedValue'].value;
```

but if you want to always subscribe to changes then you can do like below.

```
ngOnInit() {
    const selectValueControl = this.form.get('selectedValue');
    selectValueControl.valueChanges.forEach(
      (value: string) => console.log(value)
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a difference between this method and the one suggested by Harry above - where you create a variable and bind it to the form's control: this.form = this.formBuilder.group({ progress: [this.progress] })

Comment: No difference, both are Model-driven. I just elaborated the answer and gave you two options to get the value. If it helped, you could accept it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

Here in this attempt...

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="progress" [value]="progress">
```

in reactive forms, `[value]` is totally ignored, you need to set the value you want for the `FormControl`. So if you want to set the variable `progress` as the initial value, you'd want to do this:

```
form: FormGroup;
progress = 'InProgress'

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.form = fb.group({
    progress: [this.progress] // here!
  });
}
```

just like you noticed.

`progress` variable is completely different from the formcontrol `progress`. The only thing is that they share the same name, but Angular can't know that you want the initial value of the form control to have the same value as your variable `progress` unless you tell Angular so.

In this case I also don't see the need of even using a variable `progress`, you can simply set the initial value as `inProgress` when you build the form:

```
this.form = fb.group({
  progress: ['InProgress']
});
```

Comment: I see, thank you, it is not a real binding then - so when I change the value in the form and submit the form - I probably won't be able to access it through "progress" variable and will need to get it from the form as "form.get('progress').value"?

Comment: Your assumption is completely correct, your formcontrol `progress` is completely separate from your your variable `progress`. The same name is probably confusing you a bit, so just think of them as any other two different variables :)

Comment: Maybe it could also be showcased if you inspect those two, your variable `progress` is a string, whereas the form control `progress` is an object, so they are not even of the same type :)